# Django Returns `Cannot assign "1": "Likes.user_id" must be a "Users" instance.`

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-views, django-related-manager

I have these `models` and I have burnt all the night trying to figure how I could save to `Likes` table but it won't just work.

```
class Users(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class Posts(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=480)

class Likes(models.Model):
    post_id = models.ForeignKey('Posts', related_name='likes_set')
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users')
    status = models.IntegerField()
```

Say `user_id1 = 1` and truly exist in the table, `post_id11 = 11` and also exist, and this user clicks on this post.

Now I want to save to Likes table and this is what I did;

```
user = Users.objects.get(id = user_id1)
post = user.posts_set.get(id = post_id11)
try:
    liked = post.likes_set.get(user_id = user_id1)
except Likes.DoesNotExist:
    liked = None
if liked:
    liked.status = F('status') - 1
    liked.save()
    total_likes = liked.status
    return HttpResponse(total_likes)
else:
    post.likes_set.create(user_id = user_id1, post_id = post_id11, status = 1)
    post.likes = F('likes') + 1
    post.save()
    total_likes = post.likes
    return HttpResponse(total_likes)
```

And this the **ERROR:**
`ValueError at /myapp/likeRecorder/
Cannot assign "1": "Likes.user_id" must be a "Users" instance.`

I have googled all night trying to solve this. Help!

Answer (score 0):

In `post.likes_set.create(user_id = user_id1, post_id = post_id11, status = 1)` replace `user_id = user_id1` with `user_id = user`, because you defined `user` before, `user = Users.objects.get(id = user_id1)`.

In terms of assignment Django checks the type of the variable when you give it to `manager.create`.

Also, you don't have to name your `ForeignKey` as `xxx_id`. I think it is not very semantic.

Comment: This didn't work. It returns `Likes matching query does not exist.`

Comment: In the same line `post_id = post_id11` should be changed to `post_id = post` for the same reason. This way the two ForeignKey's requirements are both satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The ID attribute for the `ForeignKey` named `foo` is named `foo_id`. Since you've gone and named your FK `user_id` for... some... "reason", the ID attribute is named `user_id_id`.

Comment: Thank you but it returns `DoesNotExist at /myapp/likeRecorder/
Likes matching query does not exist.` after changing `user_id` to `user_id_id` and I also tried changing `post_id` to `post_id_id` but error is still the same.

Comment: Funny enough, I just checked my DB and it is updating as I click on the posts but the code is still returning the error.

Comment: Why don't you add your error traceback in the question, its hard to understand why this error occured from one line.